# Symfony3 PostPersist works in local but not in prod

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I have a basic User entity with a post persist listener in a file named UserCreatedListener.php which contains the following code :

```
<?php

namespace Thiveo\AppBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Thiveo\AppBundle\Manager\User\GrayProfileManager;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Entity\Alert;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Entity\CreditStack;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Service\MailerService;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Entity\User;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Service\TransformerService;
use Thiveo\CoreBundle\Service\UserService;
use Thiveo\WorkflowBundle\Event\WorkflowEvent;
use Thiveo\WorkflowBundle\Model\WorkflowModel;

class UserCreatedListener
{
    /**
     * @var UserService
     */
    protected $userService;

    /**
     * @var GrayProfileManager
     */
    protected $grayProfileManager;

    /**
     * CreateUserListener constructor.
     * @param UserService $userService
     * @param GrayProfileManager $grayProfileManager
     * @internal param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(
        UserService $userService,
        GrayProfileManager $grayProfileManager
   ) {
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->grayProfileManager = $grayProfileManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postPersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        dump("blabla");die;
    }
}
```

I configured the service in a yml file like this :

```
services:

    Thiveo\AppBundle\Listener\UserCreatedListener:
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: Thiveo\CoreBundle\Entity\User, event: postPersist }
```

It seems to work all the time (local and production included) except in one case.

I use a symfony command which creates a new user, on my local version it goes through the listener like it's supposed to do, but it doesn't in my prod version.

I've tried to put a try-catch on the flush line on my production version, where it is supposed to create the user, but there isn't any exception thrown and the flush works fine.

Does anyone can help through this ?

Comment: "It seems to work all the time (local and production included) except in one case." Can you maybe elaborate what that case is and how it differs from the other times when it works? Otherwise we can only guess, e.g. maybe you are using DQL then the events are not triggered.